# cannot use ${aspnet-request-ip}

Tags: .net-core, nlog

here is my layout:

```
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${aspnet-request-ip}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
  </targets>
```

${aspnet-request-ip} part does not work.

I have installed both nlog and nlog.web. Both are in dotnet core 
version.

Comment: Have you tried to activate the internal logger, and check for warnings and errors? https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging

Comment: Have you updated to latest NLog 4.5-rc07 + NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.5.0-rc3 and checked your config-code matches the Wiki: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2

Answer (score 2):

I have to add an extension to make it works (this was left off in the official document)

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

...
```

@Rolf thank you :)

Comment: Strange NetCoreApp2 with Net4.5-rc07 shouldn't need explicit loading of `NLog.Web.AspNetCore`. Anyway next version of `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` will include https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/249 (That should make it work for NetCoreApp1 also)

Comment: thank you for letting me know! looking forward to it to come out :D

Comment: This should not be needed anymore in NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.5.0, which was released a few days ago